# Unable to click entire row in custom Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I am creating a custom ListView in which I have two identical rows and one is different with a Spinner in it. The problem is that the row with Spinner is not clickable. I can only click on Spinner. Here is my adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int theType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            if (theType == 0) {
                convertView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.row_item0, parent, false);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.sp = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sp);

            } else if (theType == 1) {
                convertView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.row_item1, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.text);
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String it = items.get(position);
        if (it != null) {
            if (theType == 0) {
                holder.textView.setText(it);
                holder.sp.setAdapter(new CategorySpinnerAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.item_spinner_category, Data.lose_weight_type));
                holder.sp
                        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {
                                Data.user
                                        .setLose_weight_type(Data.lose_weight_type
                                                .get(position));
                                Data.user.setGoal(Data.goals.get(0));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
            } else if (theType == 1) {
                holder.textView.setText(it);
            }

        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any clickable widget like Image Button, spinner , button etc are included in adapter then list view item is not clickable.

You can do one things you can make click listener on convert view in adapter class itself. This may not be accurate method, but this works perfectly in this kind of situation

Comment: I did not understand. what do you mean by click listener on convert view in adapter?

Comment: it worked but I don't understand why Android developers haven't fixed this issue yet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your layout file of the custom listview or in each of the views add `android:focusable="false"`. If any of the view in custom listview has focusable view then onitemclick does not work.

Comment: Wow! I didn't knew about the android:descendantFocusability attribute, but this attribute does the trick! Instead I always used setFocusable(false) in code, because I experienced that the focusable attribute does not work.